# Small glitch in review pages popup z-index

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, design

The "Should this question be closed as " expandable popup, which scrolls with page, gets an higher z-index than the close popup, when the page is not at the top like here:

[image: help popup overlays close popup]

Steps to reproduce:

1. open review page (ie: close votes)  and scroll to top of question
2. click (more) link to open description
3. click close button to open close popup

I use chromium 23 on linux.

If page is scrolled back to the top with both popups open, the help popup returns behind the close popup.

Additionally, when the "(less)" link is clicked, both popups are closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The z-index issue will be addressed next time we build; thanks for pointing that out.

Re the issue at the end:

> Additionally, when the "(less)" link is clicked, both popups are closed.

Clicking *anywhere* outside the popup closes the popup; that is by design.